# Vue cannot find the dynamic source of the vuetify v-img element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to load an image (from my file system and not url) dynamically with vuetify. However, when I bind a path variable in v-img element, vue cannot find it. When I put it statically using the "required" method, it is ok.

How can I choose a dynamic path with vuetify? Is this a problem with the file loader?

I expect to select the image in run time dynamically. For example, if I have "next" button, I want to load the next image. Here is the code in Vue.js

```
<html>   
   <v-img 
      v-bind:src="require(myPath)"
      aspect-ratio="1.5"
      max-height="500"
      contain
   />
</html>

<script>    
    data: () => ({
        mycount: 1,
        myPath: "../myimages/2.png"
    })
</script>
```

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '../myiamges/2.png'" found in --->     at src/App.vue  vue.runtime.esm.js:619
>       Error: "Cannot find module '../imyimages/2.png'"
>           webpackEmptyContext components sync:2
>           render Gamesheet.vue:30
>           VueJS 21
>           run es6.promise.js:75
>           notify es6.promise.js:92
>           flush _microtask.js:18
>       vue.runtime.esm.js:1888

Comment: When I change the path into a url path and remove the require method, it works. For example: 
v-bind:src=myPath
myPath: "https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png",

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a long research and tries I found the answer of my own question.

The problem here is with the method "require". It needs to know the folder where the images are, during the compilation, when I use a dynamic path. See [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression). So giving the path including the file name dynamically won't enable the "require" method to identify the folder only. That was imy interpretation.

So I modifed the code like this and it worked for me:

```
<html>   
   <v-img 
      v-bind:src="require('../myimages/' + myFilename)"
      aspect-ratio="1.5"
      max-height="500"
      contain
   />
</html>

<script>    
    data: () => ({
        mycount: 1,
        myFilename: "2.png"
    })
</script>
```

In this case, I could change myFilename in the runtime and it worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too:

```
<v-img 
    :src="`${image-variable}`">
</v-img>
```

This worked in Vuetify 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Try using computed properties, something like:

```
<html>   
   <v-img 
     v-bind:src="require(imageSrc)"
     aspect-ratio="1.5"
     max-height="500"
     contain
   />
</html>

<script>    
   data: () => ({
      mycount: 1,
      myPath: "../myimages/2.png"
   }),
computed: {
   imageSrc() {
      return this.myPath;
   }
}
</script>
```

This will make the imageSrc be a dynamic variable, but you said about clicking a "next" button, this click need to change the "myPath" value then "imageSrc" will change and the v-img will get this new value;

Comment: the problem still exists after implemting the computed property.
The same error occured. Vue.js somehow interprets the dynamic path correctly as the error says, but it still cannot find the file. On the other side, a static path is still working.